# title after select cell on UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationbar, title

I created tableview and detailviewcontroller but once I select cell for example:I select the row Dog it's not writer Dog on navigationbar.  How to do it?

I use with this code

But it's a warning that says local declaration of 'tableview' hides instance variable

DVC =DetailViewController

```
DVC.title = [[[self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] textLabel] text];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is not standard behavior of a UITableView. It only changes the Title if you switch to another ViewController.

You need to implement the method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` in the ViewController. There you manually change the title of the Navigationbar.

I'm not 100% sure, but I think with that line of code you can change the title:

```
[viewController.navigationItem setTitle:@"Whatever you want"];
```

Edit:

The warning just says, that you have an instance variable called `tableview` and the delegate method also passes internally a variable called `tableview`. So just change the instance variable name which has the reference to the UITableView.

Comment: it's not is. this is change your title navigationcontroller.

Comment: Don't you wanna change the title of the navigationbar? Or what did you mean by: "it's not writer Dog on navigationbar"? :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this method: [self setTitle:@"Dog"];

Answer (score 0):

You should set your detailviewcontroller's title. You can set in your tableView's delegate method: didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

```
detailViewController.navigationController.title = @"Dog";
```

About your warning, it's because you have declared a variable called tableView but in the method you write

```
DVC.title = [[[self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] textLabel] text];
```

there is also a variable called tableView.

Comment: You want to show "Dog" on tableView or the detailViewController?

Comment: I need replace all tableView for example tragetView?

Comment: What do you mean 'tragetView', you want to say 'targetView'. But what's relationship between 'targetView' and 'tableView'?